# While trying to connect to a server get two different errors 10056 and 10061

Tags: c++, winsock

This is a program i use to test

```
SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int noDelay = 1;
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, reinterpret_cast < const char* >(&noDelay), sizeof(noDelay)

sockaddr_in serverAddress;
serverAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serverAddress.sin_family           = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port             = htons(static_cast<unsigned short int>(port));

iResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
iResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
```

from the start after second connect i have WSAError set to 10056 - pretty understandible, but in some tries i start to get 10061 even with first call to connect. I think it starts to happen at 5 or 6 program execution.

Why it could be?

UPDATE:

At least i souldn't call connect twice with one socket:)

Comment: 10056 == Socket is already connected, which does make sense, since you are calling connect twice on s.  10061 == Connection (actively) refused.  This might be a local firewall trying to prevent connection flooding, or it could be the remote device is refusing connections because you look like you are SYN flooding after several rapid connections.  Not answering because I don't know for certain.

Comment: @Speed8ump , thanks this is what i thinking about for now.